# Error accessing struct from source file using extern

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to C, and I was reading about `extern`. I used it with built-in data types and it worked fine, however when I tried to use it with structs, it gave the following error. What am I doing wrong?

**bar.c**

```
struct MyX
{
    int x;
} X;
```

**foo.c**

```
extern struct MyX X;
int main()
{
    X.x=80;
    return 0;
}
```

> gcc -o barfoo foo.c bar.c
>   `error:` invalid use of undefined type 'struct MyX'

```
 X.x=80;
 ^
```

Comment: Please put more effort in your question title. Nobody will find this question with this title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `gcc -o barfoo foo.c bar.c` (which should really be `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g foo.c bar.c -o barfoo`; you should always enable all warnings and debugging info when compiling your code) is compiling two *compilation units* (`foo.c` and `bar.c`) then [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) their [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) together.

Every compilation unit (or [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit)) is "self-sufficient" regarding C declarations; you should declare every -non-predefined- type (e.g. `struct`) you are using in a translation unit, often in some common header file.

So you should have

```
struct MyX {
  int x;
};
```

and

```
extern struct MyX X;
```

in both `foo.c` & `bar.c`. To avoid copy-pasting, you probably want to put that in some `myheader.h` and use `#include "myheader.h"` at start of both `foo.c` and `bar.c`, i.e. use

```
// file myheader.h
#ifndef MYHEADER_INCLUDED
#define MYHEADER_INCLUDED
struct MyX {
  int x;
};
extern struct MyX X;
#endif /* MYHEADER_INCLUDED */
```

Notice the *conventional* use of an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Read more about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), e.g. [documentation of GNU `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

Some programming languages (e.g. Ocaml, Rust, Go, ... but not C, and not yet C++) have *modules* or *packages* to deal with that issue.

<sup>PS. You should study the source code of some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) coded in C. You'll learn a lot.</sup>

Comment: Still showing same error. How to declare this non-predefined type struct in header file?